# What arguments to pass method to get different properties of an object depending on caller? Method signature and implementation

Tags: c#, wcf, methods, signature, contract

**Some architecture introduction before I formulate the problem**

I have many WCF services; ServiceLargeObject, ServiceA, ServiceB, ServiceC, ..., ServiceZ.

I have a WCF contract describing a large object that each service has access to in the form of a NuGet package. All services agree on what the large object looks like.

The large object has many properties of different types:

```
class LargeObject {
public int Prop1 { get; set; }
public string Prop2 { get; set; }
public bool Prop3 { get; set; }
public CustomProp Prop4 { get; set; }
public List<OtherCustomProp> Prop5 { get; set; }
...
public decimal Prop25 { get; set; }
}
```

ServiceLargeObject is responsible for CRUD-operations of the large object. If the other services want to do something with a LargeObject, they call ServiceLargeObject to operate.

Le's say ServiceA wants to update Prop1 of a LargeObject. It asks ServiceLargeObject for the object by its unique identifier (a value of one of the props), it gets the object, it changes the value of Prop1 and it tells ServiceLargeObject to update and save the updated LargeObject.

ServiceLargeObject receives the updated data from ServiceA, converts LargeObject to a MiddleLayerLargeObject, and passes it to a middle layer.

The middle layer performs logic on the MiddleLayerLargeObject.

To finally perform CRUD-operations, the MiddleLayerLargeObject is once again converted to a FinalLayerLargeObject and sent to the final layer responsible for talking to the DB.

**The problem**

Most of the service rarely need more than a few props from LargeObject. They always get the full LargeObject which is an enormous waste of data sent. They are some specialized service methods on ServiceLargeObject that will only get certain data for requesting services. These are implemented because that data is often requested. Most of the time, however, the best thing that could happen would be if the service could simply request exactly the props they wanted from LargeObject, and get only those.

What I am looking for is a solution to achieving just that. How does the method look? What is it's signature? What is it's implementation? **To clarify, this is about getting data. Reading.** If this can be solved I will be very interested in updating data as well, but that's for another time.

Example:
ServiceB wants Prop3, Prop5 and Prop20 from LargeObject
ServiceK want Prop1 and Prop25.
SerivceQ wants Prop2, Prop13, Prop14, Prop16, Prop19.
...and so on for all services. Different service, different props. **One method**

something like:
public XXXXX GetJustTheRequestedLargeObjectProperties(YYYYY arguments)

But there are a few constraints.

**Constraints**

- LargeObject will not change. It will remain LargeObject.
- It is OK to add another service method to hopefully replace old ones. This is what I want.
- It is OK to add middle layer objects and final layer objects. There can be more methods of talking to the DB.
- It is - I think - OK to add attributes to LargeObject, if LargeObject remains backwards compatible. I.e. services that do not get the updated contract can still use ServiceLargeObject.
- It does not matter how the return value looks, as long as I know which values are returned. I.e. since I can expect certain props, it does not matter if they arrive as a predictable collection, an anonymous object, or something else.
- **Preferably** No reflection (not sure if it can be solved without)
- Preferably no enums, since they tend to create problems with backwards compatibility over time in WCF Contracts.

I know this is very abstract and unspecified, but I'm hoping you might have ideas on approaches or maybe even solutions. Maybe Attributes are the solution. Maybe expressions. I have been searching for a long time not reaching a good solution.

Thanks, and sorry for the long read!

PS. If you have thoughts on updating LargeObject by property (instead of the whole object every time), that would be greatly appreciated as well. But that's a bonus. Thanks, again.

Comment: I think this cannot be achieved unless you define a different LargeObject for each WCF service.

Comment: @DingPeng I was thinking either to add attributes to the LargeObject, perhaps a byte or string value, which could be used as an identifier to be encoded/decoded so that properties could be requested by their byte/string/enum value.
Or, to use one of the following methods (not reflection, but create delegate perhaps):
https://mattwarren.org/2016/12/14/Why-is-Reflection-slow/

Do you think that could be possible?